# how to gettext in edittext to array

Tags: android

How can I get the value of EditText then store it in my array?

This is my full code:

```
EditText op = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.operator);
array=new int [Integer.valueOf(op.getText().toString())];

for (i = 0;i<(array.length+1);i++){
    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View v2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputangka, null) ;
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("number of-"+(i-1)+":")
        .setView(v2)
        .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                EditText number = (EditText)v2.findViewById(R.id.number);
                int number1 = Integer.valueOf(number.getText().toString());
                array [i]= number1; //error line
```

My error log:

```
02-05 16:33:31.374: E/AndroidRuntime(431): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `for (i = 0;i<(array.length+1);i++)` - Seems like that's your problem. The +1 puts you beyond the last index in the array.

Comment: i have remove +1 and i am compile again but my error same,,,,on array [i]= number1;

Answer (score 1):

This occur because for ex you enter 5 in edit text. Now you are iterate the loop until less than 6 from initial value 0.

When counter reach to 5  then your condition will become true 5 < 6 then but there array size is 5 here you are accessing the 6th element. So it throwing the `ArrayIindexOutOfBound Exception`.

To get rid from this problem.

**Try this.**

```
for (i = 0; i<(array.length);i++){
    //Code
}
```

Comment: The second one will not actually cause an exception. It would just set the title to `"number of--1:"`, `"number of-0:"`, and so on.

Comment: i have removed then my problem is same,,,,,

Comment: @user1759316 Same error then post the logcat i can not imagine

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.example.dialog_looping.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: @user1759316 What is written on MainActivity.java:48 and have you made change in java file what i have told above and make sure you have compiled the java class.

Comment: this is my full code and my error logcat https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C_dar_55SyqBbT2RMpwx11KH210UKxK5rzqTwNaKGvg/edit

Answer (score 0):

remove +1 from  `for (i = 0;i<(array.length+1);i++){` and it will work like a charm.

Comment: same error, this is my error logcat and my full code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C_dar_55SyqBbT2RMpwx11KH210UKxK5rzqTwNaKGvg/edit

Comment: yeah, sorry i am newbie, please give me code for looping dialog,,,

Comment: I will give it, But what is the logic, I mean what you are trying to do?

Comment: i want to create dialog loop, if i am input 3 then dialog looping 3x, and my value on dialog loop store in array then show. if on dialog looping 1st iam input 10 then dialog show 10, 2nd dialog i am input 20 then dialog show 10+20,i am input 3rd 30 then dialog show 10+20+30 and etc depending on the input number of looping dialog

Comment: please wait i am upload my design

Comment: this is my design https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7q89RJoiygvWm1lWU1aOVhaS1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace the for condition by following code.

```
for (i = 0;i<(array.length-1);i++){
```

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

See, your `onClick()` is getting executed after your loop is finished executing and hence the value of `i` is one more than the array last index. For a workaround, save that value into another temporary integer variable and then send it. It will surely work then.